# Cant work out where brackets go in formula

Tags: excel, reference, excel-formula

I have the following formula

```
=eval("=count("&"Sheet1!$H$5:"&wColLastRowAdd("Sheet1","H"))
```

This works fine, where wColLastRowAdd is a function to give the address of the last row

```
Public Function wColLastRowAdd(worksheetNm As String, colNm As String) As String
wColLastRowAdd = Worksheets(worksheetNm).Range(colNm & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Address
End Function
```

and function to turn the string address into a formula address

```
Function Eval(Ref As String)
Application.Volatile
Eval = Evaluate(Ref)
End Function
```

I am now trying to work out how to make my formula into a countif formula

I just cant seem to get this to work, this is my last attempt

```
=eval("=countif("&"Sheet1!$H$5:"&wColLastRowAdd("Sheet1","H"),">0"&")")
```

I just cant seem to work out where the "" are supposed to go to make the formula evaluate correctly i just keep getting the dreaded #VALUE!

Comment: Why are you concatenating two constants? i.e. `"=countif("&"Sheet1!$H$5:"`  If I were you, I would just figure out the `countif()` formula in a worksheet, and then just replace the very specific part that needs to be dynamic in your `eval`

Comment: You are missing a few &s and "s `=eval("=countif(Sheet1!$H$5:"&wColLastRowAdd("Sheet1","H")&","">0"")")`

Comment: Hey Scott im seeing you all over the place these days, yep that works perfectly many thanks

Comment: I am in a slow time at work.  So I come here to learn and help.  This keeps me sharp.

Comment: Nice, well at the top of your game ;)

Answer (score 0):

The same has been answered through comment, hence the question marked as unanswered. So, answering here behalf of **Scott Craner**

You are missing a few &s and "s

`=eval("=countif(Sheet1!$H$5:"&wColLastRowAdd("Sheet1","H")&","">0"")")`